# UK Visa for Algerians

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, algerian-citizens

I am Algerian, I teach English at high school and I want to ask about the process of applying for a UK Visa from Algiers. I would like to spend few days there.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the application process? The UK Government website has lots of information that should help: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: Are you going there as a tourist?